# Video system not initialized even though I did initialized it

Tags: compiler-errors, pygame

I get the error video system not initialized even though I did initialize it. When I do it without creating classes, I do not get the error. Can somebody please explain this to me.

See code below:

```
from pygame import *
import pygame

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.exitgame = False
        self.surface = (640, 500)
        pygame.init()

    def setup(self):
        display.set_mode(self.surface)
        display.update()

    def exitapp(self):
        if self.exitgame:
        quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = App()
    game.setup()
    switch = {QUIT: quit()}
    while not game.exitgame:
        for event in event.get():
            switch.get(event.type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, screen isn't stored properly, make it an attribute and it will help you later.

Secondly, in the switch dictionary, the quit function is ran always, and does not work within the event loop.

Third, you are importing pygame twice.

Fourth, don't use quit, use pygame.quit().

Fifth, there are several useless functions that can be removed with no affect to the app class.

Here is the correct code:

```
import pygame

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.exitgame = False
        self.surface = (640, 500)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.surface)

    def setup(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = App()
    game.setup()
    while not game.exitgame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game.exitgame = True

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. But in my code there is some interesting thing i found trying. when i comment the switch definition, the code is not giving me any error, but when i do use that switch definition I am getting the initialization error. Can you please explain me why this is happening?

Comment: And yes, i changed the quit()to pygame.quit().